# php messing up link

Tags: php, hyperlink, external

I'm trying to create a link as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?= $linkAddress ?>&t<?= $message ?>">
```

however, when I click the link, it takes me to the correct URL, but preceeded with:

```
http://pal.sandbox.dev.co.uk/go/music/artists/profile/show/ext/_auto/-/
```

which is (close to) the address of the page I've just come from.  Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

*to clarify:*

the html generated is:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fprogrammes%2Fp001d7pg&t=My+music+was+broadcast">
```

but clicking this link takes the user to the address:

```
http://pal.sandbox.dev.co.uk/go/music/artists/profile/show/ext/_auto/-/http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.co.uk%2Fprogrammes%2Fp001d7pg&t=My+music+was+broadcast
```

Comment: can you post here HTML code of the link? (Not PHP)

Comment: seems like you missing some info, question is not making to much sense

Comment: I've clarified the question now..

Comment: i do not see how a link to fb takes you to http://pal.sandbox.dev.co.uk <a> tags are pretty widely used and are not known for random url opening

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?= $linkAddress ?>&t=<?= $message ?>">
missing the = after t
```

Comment: thanks - the '=' was missing.  however, this hasn't fixed the issue, as the address navigated to on clicking is still preceeded by an unwanted string

Comment: http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://dogmatic69.com&t=foo works fine, i think $linkAddress is not what you think it is or there is other code you not telling about.

Comment: also t=foo does nothing as seen above, i dont see foo anywhere

Comment: I have printed $linkAddress in a span to make sure it is what it should be.  I have also attached the generated html to the question, which confirms the link is as it should be.The problem is that extra information is getting added to the start of the URL when it is navigated to, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out that this is caused by javascript not php (disabling javascript fixes the problem).  I haven't written any of this site's javascript, unfortunately, so will have to trawl through it looking for bugs..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've worked this out by now but this is something called go tracking. It's an internal BBC thing so come and ask in #frameworks in IRC if you need help.